# How can I loop over an array of objects without Object.keys()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, loops, object

I'm a beginner at JavaScript and I'm trying to solve this problem **without** `Object.keys()` or any regex. I have a working solution but I'm wondering if there's a better way to call on the object key within the array while still looping. If anyone has a way to do this that's basic please let me know.

**Problem:**
Create a function called keyCount which accepts two parameters, an array of objects, and a string. The function should return a number which is the number of times that key appears in the array of objects.

**Expected Result:**
`countTimesOfKey([{name:"Sharon"}, {name: "Manish"},{lastName: "Terma"}], "name")) // 2`

**My Answer:**

```
function countTimesOfKey(arr, str) {
  let count = 0

  for (let i in arr){
    let test = arr[i]
    let test2 = test[str]

   if (test2 !== undefined){
      count += 1
    }
  }
  return count
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the items in the array which have `str` as a property (by using [`Object.hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)), then return the length of the resulting array:

```js
function countTimesOfKey(arr, str) {
  return arr.filter(e => e.hasOwnProperty(str)).length;
}

console.log(countTimesOfKey([{
  name: "Sharon"
}, {
  name: "Manish"
}, {
  lastName: "Terma"
}], "name"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, using `Object.keys()` and [@Spectric](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69036003/5625547)'s solution are way better than the one below, I just wanted to show that we can even more 'simplify' this.

---

We can use [`for...in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to

- Loop over each object in the array
- Loop over each key of the object on the current index

  - Compare the name of each key against our check variable

    - Increase our counter
- `return` the result counter

```js
const result = countTimesOfKey([{name:"Sharon"}, {name: "Manish"},{lastName: "Terma"}], "name");
console.log(result);

function countTimesOfKey(arr, name) {
    let counter = 0;
    for (a in arr) {
        for (let k in arr[a]) {
            if (k === name) {
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```